# Infinitif passé ou infinitif présent

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, infinitif, temps-composés

La phrase

> Je vous remercie d'avoir voyagé.

utilise un infinitif passé (*avoir* suivi du participe passé).

Pourquoi est-ce que dans la première phrase ci-dessous je ne peux pas utiliser l'infinitif passé mais dans la deuxième je peux l'utiliser ?

> Je t'ai entendu avoir parlé de moi. (faux)
>
> Je t'ai remercié d'avoir fait ce voyage.  (ok)

Comment: Note à ceux qui répondent: comme l'indique très clairement le titre, la question porte sur le temps grammatical de l'infinitif dans ces phrases. Toute autre correction peut être effectuée directement en modifiant la question. La question est générale et n'est pas restrainte à ces exemples qui ne font que l'illustrer.

Comment: J'ai supprimé les réponses qui ne faisaient que corriger des points secondaires de la formulation précédente de la question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je vous remercie de faire ce voyage

(Maintenant, dans le présent) *je vous remercie de faire ce voyage* (dans le présent ou dans le futur, infinitif présent)

> Je vous remercie d'avoir fait ce voyage

(Maintenant, dans le présent) *je vous remercie d'avoir fait ce voyage *(dans le passé, infinitif passé, le voyage est antérieur)

> Je l'ai remercié d'avoir fait ce voyage

(Dans le passé) *Je l'ai remercié d'avoir fait ce voyage* (dans le passé, infinitif passé, le voyage ne s'est pas effectué au moment du remerciement)

Les deux actions ne sont pas synchrones

---

> Je t'ai entendu avoir parlé de moi (incorrect)

(Dans le passé) *Je t'ai entendu avoir parlé de moi* (dans le passé).

Différence : on est obligé d'entendre lorsque les paroles sont émises. Les deux actions sont obligatoirement simultanées.
L'action relative à l'infinitif passé (avoir parlé), ne peut être exécutée avant celle de référence (j'ai entendu).

> Je t'ai entendu parler de moi

Au moment où j'ai entendu (tes paroles), tu parlais de moi (et non *tu avais parlé*, sinon je n'aurai pas pu les entendre).

Answer (score 0):

*Je t'ai vu avoir parlé à propos de moi*: Que ce soit voir ou parler, cela ne peut pas être sur ce qui s'est déjà passé !

Comment: Je comprend pas "Je t'ai vu avoir parlé à propos de moi: Que ce soit voir ou parler, cela ne peut pas être sur ce qui s'est déjà passé !"
Qu'est ce que tu veux dire par la?